# Can an external table be created in Redshift in specific directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-redshift, external, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have created an external table that reads the files of all the folders that are in the specified path using the following script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.eventos_ne9 (
event_date varchar(300),
event_timestamp varchar(300),
event_name varchar(300)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/myfolder/events_/'
```

Now I just want to point to the files that start with 201812.
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB0XZ.png)

I have been trying in the following way, but it does not save any data:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.eventos_ne9 (
event_date varchar(300),
event_timestamp varchar(300),
event_name varchar(300)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/myfolder/events_/201812.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'s3://mybucket/myfolder/events_/201812'` because this already specifies a prefix. The `*` at the end is assumed.

Comment: Hello, it was one of the options I tried. But it has not worked

Comment: This works for normal Redshift `COPY` loads, but I guess it doesn't work for Redshift Spectrum. The documentation shows the format as `{ 's3://bucket/folder/' | 's3://bucket/manifest_file'`, so I guess it needs a folder rather than a file prefix.